# Tennis: why can doubles players have a partner from a different country?

Tags: rules, tennis

Why are players able to choose partners from different countries in doubles' tennis?

For example, [Sania Mirza](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sania_Mirza) and [Marina Hingis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martina_Hingis) are from different countries but they play together.

Comment: Might it be because they are members of the same human race?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tennis in an individual sport. In grand slams, ATP, WTA people are individual participants. They are not playing for their country. Therefore the players can choose any partner they want. There are other tournaments like Davis cup and Olympics. In these tournaments players represent their country and the partners are from their own country.